# plsql procedure gets invalidated

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, dblink

procedure involving dblinks gets invalidated regularly .we need to recompile every time.How to find what is causing the problem

in my case

```
procedure p1()--resides in db1
is
begin
....
select col1 from table1@db2;

...
end
/
```

for some reasons the procedure gets invalidated and the dblinks doesnt work and i get the following errors

```
ORA-04052
ORA-00604
ORA-02019
```

and i recompile all the invalid objects this seem to work.

i need to figure why the proc in db1 gets invalidated?

Comment: if the db link doesn't work, (ora-2019) indicates that db-link perhaps changed? that alone is probably sufficient to invalidate your procedure P1. Check who/why the db link is getting changed?

Comment: hi raj,how can i check who/why the db link changed.u mean auditing

Comment: can REMOTE_DEPENDENCIES_MODE =  SIGNATURE be used to overcome this problem

Comment: the table1 in "table1@db2", is that a synonym? if the stack trace includes kqlhdlod you may be hitting bug 10210507. Workaround is to change table1 to a view and then use view1@db2. YMMV, do test carefully.